# Passing function arguments into django model instance

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a function that saves model to database based on dictionary of items provided.

```
def bulk_creator_product_segment(df_records):
    """
    Create object in Product segment model
    Saves objects in bulk based on unique constraint
    """
    model_instances = [models.Product_segment(
        name=record["SegmentName"],
        product_category=models.Product_category.objects.get(name=record["CategoryName"]),
    ) for record in df_records]

    models.Product_segment.objects.bulk_create(model_instances, ignore_conflicts=True)
```

Now I am trying to make it reusable and move things that change to function arguments. However I am having a problem with converting the `name` and `product_category` which are model field into function argument, which would mean something like this:

```
bulk_creator_product_segment(df_records, firstfield, secondfield):


    model_instances = [models.Product_segment(
        firstfield=record["SegmentName"],
        secondfield=models.Product_category.objects.get(name=record["CategoryName"]),
    ) for record in df_records]
```

It will not read `firstfield` as argument but as field names in the Product_segment which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean you want those arguments as keywords in `Product_segment`? If so, you can use dict unpacking like this:

```
def bulk_creator_product_segment(df_records, firstfield, secondfield):
    model_instances = [models.Product_segment(
        **{
            firstfield: record["SegmentName"],
            secondfield: models.Product_category.objects.get(name=record["CategoryName"]),
        },
    ) for record in df_records]
```